# In hyperledger fabric, What is the main difference between 1.2v and 2.0v?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, difference

#### In `hyperledger` fabric:

What is the main difference between `1.2v` and `2.0v`?

Please explain with examples

Comment: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew.html, https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Comment: Please consider reading the main page of Hyperledger Fabric, as mentioned by Paolo above.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/whatsnew.html